# Woocommerce product list spacing

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

This is my site:

http://www.armonisencia.cl/site/

I have a woocommerce product list and after that, i have a really long margin at the bottom. I'm trying to change it with css here:

```css
.woocommerce .products ul, .woocommerce ul.products {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, like only kind of works if a shrink my Chrome's window.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Its better if you post your minimal code here as sample so that everybody will have track of issue/solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]1. If you try to edit page - maybe your theme support margins in page setup. if not - then you should find it in theme options/personalization.

2. If you do changes manually, remember to add them to the Child theme.
3. If you have the option to add custom CSS and sometimes it works sometimes not, then add !important to your CSS

   ```
   .woocommerce .products ul, .woocommerce ul.products {
   margin-bottom: 0 !important;
   padding-bottom: 0 !important;
   }
   ```

In your case you have paddings 56px as well in: .et_pb_section which together give you 112px space between.

Comment: I did it and it keeps looking the same, nothing changed.

I can't find those 56px paddings you were talking about, i think that should be the problem, but i can't find it. I'm looking on the child-theme's css and in the custom css and i don't have that anywhere.

Comment: this padding on mobile is 188px

Answer (score 0):

You are using page builder to setup your page. remove the padding-top and bottom to remove space.